# Windows Azure website Merge branch 'master' - removed resource

Tags: git, azure

so i pushed some files into my website, however i get the following after being prompted for a ssl authentication username & password kind of like those you set up with .htaccess

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I was wondering as well as to why my merge branch has an extra directory after www.MyWebsite_Name..azurewebsites.net/MyWebsite_Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with git. Does it work if you use WebDeploy or FTP?